# What is this lag plot telling me?

Tags: data-visualization, statistical-power, lags

I am working on predicting power consumption. I have been struggling to identify autocorrelation in my time series data. The lag plot created below is for power consumption over 5 minute intervals. I created it using the lag_plot function.

1.Is there something wrong with my data? What is this plot saying?
[image]

Comment: Knowing you used the `lag_plot` function is not very useful without knowing the language/package you got it from.  Better to describe what the function *does*.  You also cut off the y-axis label, which makes the plot harder to interpret.

Comment: I apologize. I used the lag_plot() function in pandas to create this plot. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#lag-plot. The y axis plots t + 1 time interval. Does this help?

Comment: @Matt I concur, but I will speculate (as surely you must have, too) that the missing y-axis label reads "$y(t+1)$".  Assuming that, it's a revealing plot.  It's a pity no mechanism to resolve the extensive overlapping points along the diagonal was employed: their density along the diagonal is an important feature of this dataset.

Comment: Yes.  Then the most distinguishing feature of the lag plot is the strong density of points along the diagonal line: this means that the value of your series at time t+1 is likely to be the same as at time t.  There are some regions of stronger density, which could correspond to sleeping (at the zero consumption area) or running air conditioning (in the upper middle) - but that's just speculation.  It's an interesting plot.

Comment: @Matt Exactly.  We can go further: there are horizontal and vertical sections of points that appear to document gradual, regular transitions between constant levels of energy usage.  The time-series plot would confirm that--or even lightly connecting the points in temporal order in this plot might do the same.

Comment: Thank you! I was using this as one of the first steps towards building an ARIMA model. Is it safe to assume that this data lends itself well to it?

Comment: That's not so clear.  Your choice of model should depend on how you intend to use it as well as on the data characteristics.  Over long time intervals--perhaps hours, maybe days--such a model might be appropriate, because on those scales it could work to use a stationary model.  The special features hinted at in this lag plot suggest that at a five-minute level of detail the model might not be stationary.  It might consist of long periods of almost no fluctuation interspersed by periods of much greater fluctuation.

Comment: That is correct. This data is from a 3 month period that has had multiple known outages. I am thinking of bootstrapping /interpolating missing data to produce a more reliable data set for my model. Thank you both  for your insight!

Comment: It's not clear how either bootstrapping or interpolation would result in something being "more reliable". It's not like they can add information.

Comment: @Glen_b Let me rephrase, I was not sure about how robust ARIMA or other time series models were to the outages in the data set. I thought that since it is a relatively short period of time, bootstrapping might help me build a better model with the limited data that I have. Am I wrong in my assumption?

Comment: In the sense that it would make it easy to bridge gaps where there are missing values and so avoid having to figure out how to get estimates with missing values in the series (or truncate the series) there may be some argument for it but I wouldn't describe that as making anything more reliable; it's a convenience\* that may make things somewhat biased compared to a more sophisticated treatment of the issue. .... \*(not that there's anything wrong with that; I love convenience as much as the next person)